# Recursive printLinkedList function needing to print "(empty string)." in C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

```
void printLinkedList(node *head)
{

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("(empty string)");
        return;
    }

    printf("Data: %d\n", head->data);
    printLinkedList(head->next);
}
```

The problem is, if head is not equal to NULL, it will print the linked list wonderfully, but at the very end, it enters the if(head == NULL) because it's a recursive function and prints "(empty string)" for any linked list (empty or not). I only want to print "(empty string)" if it's initially empty. How would I code that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use recursion for this? (Is this a learning exercise?)

Comment: Well it was much simpler as an iterative function, but we were asked to write it recursively to get a better understanding and practice recursion so to answer your question, yes it is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive function, as it is, has no way of knowing if you are calling it for the first time or if it is being called during your walk through the list. So, even when you have a non-empty list, eventually you reach the end of the list, which in this case seems to be NULL. If you need to check if the list is empty, I would recommend writing a helper function, that does this for you and then starts the recursion for you, like this:

```
printHelper(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("(empty string)");
    }
    else
    {
        printLinkedList(head)
    }

}
```

And then take out the printf("(empty string)") from the recursive function.

Or, if you really want to keep it as a single recursive function, you could add a counter argument that increments with each recursive call, like this:

```
void printLinkedList(node *head, int counter)
{

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        if(counter == 0))
        {
            printf("(empty string)");
            return;
        }
    }                     
    else
    {
        ++counter;
        printf("Data: %d\n", head->data);
        printLinkedList(head->next, counter);
    }
}
```

And then when you call this function for the first time, pass the second argument as 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jas. The helper function is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

```
void printLinkedList(node *head)
{

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("(empty list)\n");
        return;
    }
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        printf("Data: %d\n", head->data);
        return;
    }

    printf("Data: %d\n", head->data);
    printLinkedList(head->next);
}
```

Comment: Easier to just print the data then check for `head->next == NULL` rather than repeating the printf

Comment: It may be either. It was for ease of understanding of the flow than to reduce the code.